# Options on installations of sql server 2008 express?

Tags: sql-server

I'm installing sqlserver 2008 express and I have a couple of questions,

by default on the collation, it has **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**  I'm just wondering which collation I should choose so that it can store all languages, English, Asian etc.

also this is a brand new installation on a brand new box, should I use Default Instance or a Named Instance.

Thank you,
Ray.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the default if on a new machine.

Here is a discussion on the asian chars.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/fa221a0b-fd81-4f5e-8298-2a3afecbd7ea